# Sphinx Ranged query + killlist

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

i have a sphinx instance with two indexes configured: main and delta. Both of them have sql query range.

in the delta index i have a killlist query to remove modified articles from the main index.

should this query be ranged like the content query ?

i.e.

```
source delta : main {
  sql_query_range   = SELECT MIN(id),MAX(id) FROM documents
  sql_range_step = 1000

  sql_query = SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id>=$start AND id<=$end WHERE ID > (SELECT maxID from SphinxTable)

  sql_query_killlist = SELECT id FROM documents WHERE id>=$start AND id<=$end WHERE ID > (SELECT maxID from SphinxTable)
 }
```

Comment: Your `sql_query_killlist` is the same as your `sql_query`. Is it intended?

Comment: yes, documents indexed by the delta index should be removed from preceding indexes (main)

Comment: No they shouldnt be the same, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should this query be ranged like the content query ?

No. killlists dont support ranged queries. It just runs one query.

Incidently, this:

> sql_query_range   = SELECT MIN(id),MAX(id) FROM documents

looks wrong. That is taking ALL ids from the documents table. But the sql_query has an aditional caluse using maxID from SphinxTable

Should be be something like

```
sql_query_range   = SELECT (SELECT maxID from SphinxTable),MAX(id) FROM documents
```

Otherwise your are going to be issuing lots of queries - to fetch documents that would be in main, which will never match because of the second calise.

So just do

```
sql_query = SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id>=$start AND id<=$end WHERE ID > (SELECT  maxID from SphinxTable) OR updated > (SELECT updatedts FROM SphinxTable)
sql_query_killlist = SELECT id FROM documents WHERE id <= (SELECT maxID from SphinxTable) AND updated > (SELECT updatedts FROM SphinxTable)
```

Note the change in equality. You want documents that are in the main, in your killlist. But you also only want the documents updated since the last reindex.